# Prevent Screen Activation on Android Wear

Tags: android, screen, settings, wear-os

Is there an API to change the setting of the automatic screen activation when the watch is moved? I couldn't find anything in the system or global settings.
I wear the watch at night and it lights up every time I move what is annoying..

Comment: I would want to know this as well. I want to set a geo fencing where i can tell the watch to disable tilt to wake. Reason, when I am at the computer it keeps lighting up and on a moto 360 the battery drain quickly and I can't use ambient mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 5.0.1 release of Android Wear, the two new settings "theater mode" and "tilt to wake screen" were added. There is no API at the moment to control them by an app.